# Make environment variables available when running command as sudo

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, environment-variables, sudo, curl, darwin

I am using Curl, and am having a problem trying to get it to recognize the `$http_proxy` environment variable when using `sudo curl`.  I tried putting `export http_proxy=....` in my /etc/profile and restarting the shell, to no avail.  I would rather not use `su -l` and run the command while logged in as root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in /etc/sudoers. There is a list of environmental variables that get shared between sudo and the regular user shell

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add:

```
envkeep http_proxy
```

to your sudoers file.  Check your sudo environmental variables by running:

```
sudo -V
```

as root.  Or by running:

```
sudo sudo -V
```